# Ошибка Download failed : request timeout в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Хочу загрузить Unity Editor через Unity Hub но когда отдельные компоненты скачиваются выдаёт ошибку. Уже давно борюсь с этой проблемой. Всё перепробовал.Unity Hub переустанавливал,кэш чистил,
путь установки переименовывал и от имени администратора запускал, но ничего не помогло.Не подскажете как исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Скорее всего, ваш Unity Hub стар для версии которую вы хотите установить. Точно знать не могу, сам ищу проблему.